# Why is my keyboard not working after login with HP laptop?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, taskbar

On my HP laptop, why can't I use my keyboard and my right click cursor or click to any icon?

It  also happens to my taskbar. I cannot click it at all. It happened after I logged in my account. Before I login, I can use the keyboard and have tried to use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>. But it does not do anything on my screen. If I click right it also does not do anything.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try few steps recommended below.

> Turn off the computer and then restart it.
>
> Press the Esc key repeatedly to see if a startup menu opens.
>
> If a setup menu does not open, the integrated keyboard hardware is not
> working. The integrated keyboard in the notebook should be serviced or
> replaced. To continue using the notebook, connect a USB-wired keyboard
> to a USB port and restart the computer.
>
> If a setup menu opens, use the arrow keys to navigate the menus. If
> these keys are working in the startup menu, but then fail when Windows
> loads, the problems might be related to the keyboard software.
>
> Restart the computer.
>
> In Device Manager, uninstall and reinstall the keyboard software:
>
> In Windows, search for and open Device Manager.
>
> Click View and select Show Hidden Devices.
>
> Click the arrow next to Keyboards, right-click the keyboard device
> name, then select Uninstall to remove the device from Windows.
>
> Continue removing device names in the Keyboards category until all
> device names have been uninstalled.
>
> Restart the notebook. Right-click Start (), select Shut down or sign
> out, then select Restart.
>
> Wait for the computer to restart and open Windows.

Refer [this](https://support.hp.com/ca-en/document/c03738933) article to further troubleshoot keyboard issues with your PC.

Comment: Please read [How to reference material written by others](https://superuser.com/help/referencing). You must block quote text that has been written by some else. See [Markdown help](https://superuser.com/editing-help). I've fixed it for you this time, but please pay attention to this in future.

Comment: @DavidPostill♦, thanks for your clarification and help.